# Scatterplot between raster and point shp

Tags: arcmap, scatterplot

I have a TIFF containing soil moisture values in each cell and I have a point shapefile with only 50 points of field measurements.

How can I make a scatterplot of these 2 datasets? I know I can convert my raster into Excel files and do the comparison in Excel. Using Arcmap, how can I compare the 50 shapefile points with the underlying cells of the raster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to extract the raster value for each corresponding point. You can use the [Extract Values to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm) tool. From the documentation:

> Extracts the cell values of a raster based on a set of point features
>   and records the values in the attribute table of an output feature
>   class.

If you want to create a scatterplot in ArcMap, you can go to **View > Graphs > Create Graph...** and select the output from the tool mentioned above as the Layer/Table. More information about creating a Scatterplot in ArcMap can be found [here.](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/graphs/creating-scatter-plot-graphs.htm)